# NullpointerException and getWritable()error on my sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i want to save some data into sqlite database but it occurred error NullpointerException,i unable to find this error please tell me

DBHandler.java

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    /*public static final String TABLE_USER = "USERTABLE";
      public static final String USER_NAME = "username";
      public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
      public static final String CONFIRM_PASSWORD = "confirm_password";
      public static final String MOBILE_NO = "mobile_no";  */


    // DataBase Name
        public final static String DATABASE = "UserDetails";

        // DataBase Table Name's
        public final static String USER_TABLE = "TABLE_USER";

        // Field names of MALLS Table

        public static final String USER_NAME = "username";
        public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
        public static final String CONFIRM_PASSWORD = "confirmpassword";
        public static final String USER_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobilenumber";
        public static final String USER_EMAIL = "email";


    private static final String LOGCAT=null;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "androidsqlite.db",null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String CREATE_TABLE_USER;    
       CREATE_TABLE_USER  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                        + USER_TABLE+ " (" + USER_NAME
                        + " VARCHAR," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR,"
                        + CONFIRM_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR," + USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " VARCHAR,"
                        + USER_EMAIL+ " VARCHAR," 
                         + ")";
         Log.d(LOGCAT,"CREATE_TABLE_USER Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE_TABLE_USER";
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    public void insertUserDetails(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USER_NAME, queryValues.get("username"));
        values.put(PASSWORD, queryValues.get("password"));
        values.put(CONFIRM_PASSWORD, queryValues.get("confirmPwd"));
        values.put(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER, queryValues.get("mobileNo"));

        database.insert("CREATE_TABLE_USER ", null, values);
        database.close();

    }

    }
```

RegistrationActivity

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity {

private Context context;

private EditText userNameEdt;
private EditText passwordEdt;
private EditText cnfrmPwdEdt;
private EditText contactEdt;

private Button submitBtn;
private Button cancelBtn;

private String userName;
private String pswd;
private String cnfrmPwd;
private String contactNo;


DBHandler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    userNameEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameedt);
    passwordEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.paswordEdit);
    cnfrmPwdEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmPaswordEdit);
    contactEdt  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNoedt);

    submitBtn   =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);
    cancelBtn   =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

     handler = new DBHandler(context);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            userName = userNameEdt.getText().toString();
            pswd     = passwordEdt.getText().toString();
            cnfrmPwd = cnfrmPwdEdt.getText().toString();
            contactNo= contactEdt.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, String> queryValues =  new  HashMap<String,String>();

            queryValues.put("username", userName);
            queryValues.put("password", pswd);
            queryValues.put("confrmPwd", cnfrmPwd);
            queryValues.put("contact", contactNo);

            handler.insertUserDetails(queryValues);

        }
    });


}



 }
```

error

```
12-31 11:52:43.867: E/AndroidRuntime(820):  at   
    com.example.esecuresystrem.database.DBHandler.insertUserDetails(DBHandler.java:68)
    12-31 11:53:54.908: E/AndroidRuntime(867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-31 11:53:54.908: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-31 11:53:54.908: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at    
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
    12-31 11:53:54.908: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at   
    com.example.esecuresystrem.database.DBHandler.insertUserDetails(DBHandler.java:68)
    12-31 11:53:54.908: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at   
    com.example.esecuresystrem.RegistrationActivity$1.onClick(RegistrationActivity.java:68)
    12-31 11:53:54.908: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at           
    android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
```

Comment: Check out my answer and do changes whichever i have shown.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
handler = new DBHandler(context);
//context is only declared not initialized in activity
```

with

```
handler = new DBHandler(RegistrationActivity.this);
```

In onCreate of DBHabdler

```
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER );
```

And change

```
values.put(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER, queryValues.get("contact"));
```

Comment: @kalyanpvs i guess that is first make that causes the NPE. Gotta look at the source code of sql lite helper class.

Comment: yes..you are right..getWritableDatabase() method they are opening db using context..like this..mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(mName, 0, mFactory, mErrorHandler);

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 errors in your code..

**1.You are not create the table any where in your code..**

add this line in your `onCreate()` method of helper class

```
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
```

you are just printed the log message but not created any table..

change your method like this..

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String CREATE_TABLE_USER;    
   CREATE_TABLE_USER  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + USER_TABLE+ " (" + USER_NAME
                    + " VARCHAR," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR,"
                    + CONFIRM_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR," + USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " VARCHAR,"
                    + USER_EMAIL+ " VARCHAR," 
                     + ")";
     db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
     Log.d(LOGCAT,"CREATE_TABLE_USER Created");
}
```

**2.change your code like this..**

```
values.put(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER, queryValues.get("contact"));
```

**3.and one more modification to your code..you are inserting data into wrong table name.**.

```
 database.insert("CREATE_TABLE_USER ", null, values);
```

here you have to pass `USER_TABLE` insteead of `CREATE_TABLE_USER`

```
database.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
```

**4.context is only declared not initialized in activity so Replace**

```
handler = new DBHandler(context);
```

with

```
handler = new DBHandler(RegistrationActivity.this);
```

Comment: 4. context is not initialized in activity. add this. Makes your answer complete

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch the contact number details with the wrong key from your `HaspMap`

Try out as below:

```
 values.put(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER, queryValues.get("contact"));
```

Also you have only written a query for creating the table but not executed it so it may not have created the table. And write the table query outside the `onCreate()` Try to execute the create table query in your `onCreate()` as below:

```
 String CREATE_TABLE_USER;    
   CREATE_TABLE_USER  = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + USER_TABLE+ " (" + USER_NAME
                    + " VARCHAR," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR,"
                    + CONFIRM_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR," + USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " VARCHAR,"
                    + USER_EMAIL+ " VARCHAR," 
                     + ")";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.d(LOGCAT,"CREATE_TABLE_USER Created");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
}
```

Also your `context` is null in your `RegistrationActivity` for the `DBHandler` class. 
Provide the context as below in your `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    context=RegistrationActivity.this;
    handler = new DBHandler(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a problem to cause NullPointerException
You put "contact" in HashMap but get "mobileNo" from it

```
queryValues.put("contact", contactNo);
values.put(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER, queryValues.get("mobileNo"));
```